# Firebase functions.auth.user().onCreate no triggering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

i am trying create user with custom claim. I am using Firebase Cloud Functions. The problem is, when i create (Sign Up) an  user, the onCreate not trigger. I am following this tutorial of provided by google. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims
*I Deployed my functions and the region is us-central1*

Cloud functions version :

```
 firebase-admin": "^8.9.0
 firebase-functions": "^3.3.0
```

I am using Vue JS as Front-end

My functions/Index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.ProccessSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) =>{
   console.log("Email"+user.email);

   if (user.email){

        const customClaims = {
            admin:true
        };

        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid,customClaims)
            .then(() =>{
                const metadataRef = admin.database().ref('metadata/' +user.uid);
                return metadataRef.set({refeshTime:new Date().getTime()})
            }).catch(err =>{
                console.log(err.message)
            })
    }



});
```

My SignUpWithEmailAndPassword

```
userSignUp({dispatch},payload){
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
                .then(user =>{
                        user.user.sendEmailVerification()
                            .then(() =>
                                alert('Your account has been created! Please, verify your account'),
                                dispatch('userSignOut'),
                            ).catch(err =>{
                                console.log(err.message)
                        })
                }).catch(err =>{
                     console.log(err.message)
            })
        },
```

oAuthStateChanged

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const user = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
            await store.dispatch("autoSignIn", user);
            resolve(user)
        });
    });

    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)



    if (requiresAuth) {
        if (!user){
            next(false)
        }else {
            if (user.emailVerified){

                next();
            }else {

                alert('Please verify your account')
                await store.dispatch("userSignOut", user);
            }
        }

    } else {

        next()

    }
});
```

Comment: How do you detect that the onCreate Cloud Function is not triggered? Do you see anything in the Firebase console? Have you checked if the user has the claim?

Comment: @Reanud Tarnec I detect, when i create a new user, it's doesn't save in the database.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's doesn't save in the database"? The user is not saved in the Auth database?

Comment: If you add a `console.log` in `userSignUp` like `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password).then(user =>{ console.log('User Created'); ....});` do you see this console output in your browser console?

Comment: Yes, I see the output in browser and when say it's not saving in database, I meant if you look at my funtions/index.js I said onCreate new user save the user credentials in the database.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear... You confirm the user is correctly created in Firebase Authentication (you can see it in the Firebase console) but the `ProccessSignUp`Cloud Function does not run? Do you see the output of `console.log("Email"+user.email);` in the Cloud Functions log (in the Firebase console)?

Comment: Hey Renaud Tarnec, it's working. I didn't know that, the output of console it has to see in cloud functions log. I was looking in browser log. I totally forgo that, cloud functions is a server and it has all his log in server side. Thank you man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs), with Cloud Functions you can "emit a log line from your function, use standard JavaScript logging calls such as `console.log` and `console.error`".

Then the Cloud Functions logs are viewable either in the Firebase console, Stackdriver Logging UI, or via the firebase command-line tool.

So you should be able to confirm that your Cloud Function runs correctly (or not) by looking at, for exemple, the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

`functions.auth.user().onCreate` will not be triggered in case you use a `Custom Token` to sign in the user.

> A Cloud Functions event is not triggered when a user signs in for the first time using a custom token.

[https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#:~:text=A%20Cloud%20Functions%20event%20is%20not%20triggered%20when%20a%20user%20signs%20in%20for%20the%20first%20time%20using%20a%20custom%20token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#:%7E:text=A%20Cloud%20Functions%20event%20is%20not%20triggered%20when%20a%20user%20signs%20in%20for%20the%20first%20time%20using%20a%20custom%20token)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation while running cloud funtions locally. My `user().onCreate()` trigger function was also not triggering.

```
export const addNewUser = auth
  .user()
  .onCreate((user) => {
     // Do something
  })
```

I tried many things but everything was looking fine. Finally I updated my firebase-tools to latest version by running this command and it started working as a charm.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
```

Hope this helps someone.